# Two-sided matrix equation $AX = XB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How do you find a square matrix $X$ from an equation of the type

$AX = XB$?  ($A$ and $B$ are known square matrices)

How do I scale the solution up to multiple $A$s and $B$s for a single unknown $X$, i.e.

$\forall_{i=1...n} A_i X=XB_i$

Besides finding a solution, I would like to know what the problem is called. I am sure it pops up in lots of different research areas, and must have been solved before, but I don't know what exactly to ask Uncle Google.

Thanks you all in advance.

Comment: Keywords "Sylvester equation", "Kronecker product"

Comment: See [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353878/necessary-conditions-for-the-existence-of-solution-of-sylvester-equation-ax-xb).